# How can i download an Empty Excel file in Physical Path

Tags: c#, excel

Here I want to Down load an Empty Excel File in link Button Click Event in Physical Path.
 My Code is

```
  HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        httpResponse.Clear();
        httpResponse.ClearContent();
        httpResponse.ClearHeaders();         

        httpResponse.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + txt1.Text + ".xls");            
        string strpath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Downloads"].ToString() + txt1.Text;           
        httpResponse.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel;";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
        httpResponse.Write(style);
        httpResponse.Output.Write(sw.ToString());

        httpResponse.Flush();
        httpResponse.Close();
        httpResponse.End();
```

My AddKey in Web.Config is

```
<add key="Downloads" value="C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Downloads"/>
```

Here how can i give this add key value

Comment: "Down load" => "download"

Comment: Do you want to download a file(xls) from an HTTP URL and store it on the file system?

Comment: not file system..iwant to store in My Own Folder

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you [WebClient.DownloadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(theUrl,
        Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Downloads"].ToString(), "myXls.xls"));
}
```

Comment: iam using Http Response

Comment: @Exception `HttpResponse` is designed to send data, it represents your server's response to a client request

Comment: ok...where can i call this WebClient(),i mean after httpResponse.Output.Write(sw.ToString());